# Button inside widget android

Tags: android, eclipse, button, android-widget, android-appwidget

I have a widget and I want to put a button inside of it. How would I do this?

-Thanks

Comment: 33 questions and still no clue about the proportionality of the quality of the question with the quality of the answer...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Did you try reading the Dev Guide?

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/appwidgets/index.html

Check also Lars Vogel's tutorial here:

http://www.vogella.de/articles/AndroidWidgets/article.html